# Simple html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

Basically, i have a bunch of images, and when I click on an image it sends the image ID, to a javascript function, that sets a value which is then processed later when I submit the form so that it goes to the next page (where I can query that value in coldfusion).

Oops, forgot the question: Basically, it doesnt do what I want it too. The variable with the values are not being sent to the next page it seems!

```
<html>
<head>

<Script type="text/javascript">

function recordClick(imageid)
{ 
var myfield = document.getElementById("numSend").value = imageid
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<FORM action="nextPage.cfm" method="post">

<img src="1.png" NAME="image1" onclick="recordClick(1)"
<img src="2.png" NAME="image2" onclick="recordClick(2)"
<img src="3.png" NAME="image3" onclick="recordClick(3)"

<input type="hidden" id="numSend"/>
<input type="submit" value="Done"/>
</FORM>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `<img>` tags are not properly closed. Also your hidden input doesn't have a `name` attribute so nothing will be sent to the server when you submit the form. Try like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function recordClick(imageid) { 
        var numSend = document.getElementById("numSend");
        numSend.value = numSend + imageid.toString();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="nextPage.cfm" method="post">
        <img src="1.png" name="image1" onclick="recordClick(1)" alt="" />
        <img src="2.png" name="image2" onclick="recordClick(2)" alt="" />
        <img src="3.png" name="image3" onclick="recordClick(3)" alt="" />

        <input type="hidden" id="numSend" name="numSend" />
        <input type="submit" value="Done" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1218175, you should also give a name attribute to the hidden field: `<input type="hidden" id="numSend" name="numSend" />`. I have updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to do the trick! All I need to do now is concatentate the IDS as atm numSend is only equalling a single value, I tried using a list, but thats not the format Im looking for. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1218175, what format do you need? Could you provide an example value?

Comment: Basically, Im going to pretty much duplicate the above page, to check the user clicks the same pictures in the same order again. So, i reckon a simple string of values would be sufficent, such a "312" etc.

Comment: @user1218175, you could use the following in this case: `document.getElementById("numSend").value = document.getElementById("numSend").value + imageid;`. I've also fixed another issue with your code that I have just noticed which is the `myfield` variable that is not needed. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @user1218175, if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you may consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 1):

I see one problem with the code – the hidden field doesn't have a name attribute, so the value won't be sent.

But apart from that, there is a possibility to achieve the same result without using JavaScript, but only plain HTML + CSS. Just look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VVD3y/

if you don't click any icon, you will be just redirected to google. If you select one of the icons and click Done, you will be redirected to google with the query stackoverflow, google or mozilla. Just change the NAME attribute of every radio button, and in VALUE attributes put your image IDs.

If you'd like to send multiple values, just replace the radio buttons with checkboxes.